# Why can't I see my pictures?

Tags: asp.net, database

This has got to be me being stupid, but I can't figure out why I can see the label but not the thumbnail. Here is the code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" RepeatColumns="5" DataKeyField="ID">
        <ItemStyle />
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="VidLink1" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# "VideoPlayer.aspx?ID=" & Eval("ID") %>' >
                    <asp:Image ID="VidThumb" runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%# "videos/TrainingVideos/Thumbnail" & Eval("Thumbnail") %>'  /></asp:HyperLink>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="VidTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Here is the path to the images:
Y:\intranet\videos\TrainingVideos\Thumbnail but all I get is the red "X". "Thumbnail" is indeed the name of the field in the database and I have jpg file extensions. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need a `/` between `Thumbnail` and the `Eval(Thumbnail)`? i.e., `"videos/TrainingVideos/Thumbnail/" & Eval("Thumbnail")`.

Comment: See, I knew it was something so silly as syntax. Geez!

Comment: @Joseph: It's not really syntax, it's string values.  In the future, a really good first step in debugging things like this is to examine the resulting client-side code (not just what the page looks like in the browser).  For something like this you'd immediately see that the URL isn't what you expect it to be.

Comment: @David You are talking about viewing the source code while in a browser, right?

Comment: @Joseph: As a start, yes.  I recommend getting the hang of some browser debugging tools (FireBug, Chrome tools, etc.) as a common tool for any web development.

Comment: Cool, I appreciate it. I will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing. See if it works...

ImageUrl='<%# "videos/TrainingVideos/Thumbnail/" & Eval("Thumbnail") %>'

Comment: Yeah, as the guy above stated. yeesh. Thanks.